# Compare two similar but not identical data tables

Tags: c#, datatable, comparison

I have two data tables which have a primary key column in common but otherwise different structures as they're created from different tables. I'd like to check which rows are missing from data table B compared to A, with the aim of adding in the missing rows to the database.

I've had a look at questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164144/c-how-to-compare-two-datatables-a-b-how-to-show-rows-which-are-in-b-but-not), which provide good answers but the data tables are usually assumed to be the same.

Since I want to get a list of new rows for inserting, is there any way I can do this without iterating through the rows and checking the PKs? If I'm not mistaken, `Merge` will keep the old rows, which I don't want to resubmit to the database.

Both tables will have only a few dozen rows, a couple of hundred maximum. Would the computational hit of doing it row-by-row be negligible anyway?

**edit:** the two source tables are on different databases/servers, so I can't easily do the 
 comparison in SQL. I'd prefer the consuming application to do it anyway, as I may add some more row processing before I'm done.

Comment: I could only answer with, and suggest iteration.  I can't think of a function that will add only n rows to a data table from another data table when a record has a column value that might not exist in the the first data table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I've understood your needs correctly, but how about using Linq?  Load the keys of your 2 tables into 2 `IEnumerable<keytype>` objects, e.g. (assuming your keys are of type `int`)

```
IEnumerable<int> keys1, keys2;
// code to load the keys into these collections
// to find the keys in keys1 that are missing from keys2:
var missingKeys = keys1.Where(k1 => !keys2.Any(k2 => k2 == k1));
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks - I really should have thought of this myself, I got hung up on the fact that the majority of the table structures are different! :)

Answer (score 0):

Is it not easier/quicker to do this in SQL e.g:

```
SELECT col1 FROM table1
MINUS
SELECT col1 FROM table2
```

Comment: yes, but the two tables are actually on different databases, and probably on different servers :)