# Difference Between 2 DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, select, datatable

I have 2 DataTable and I want to create a third DataTable that contais the difference between DataTable 1 and DataTable 2.

For example, DataTable1 has the original data, and the DataTable 2 is just a copy, like a replication. But when you insert a new row in DataTable1, the DataTable2 has just insert the same row. Nowaday my code do a compare between DataTable1 and DataTable2, if not equals (1 row or more was inserted), DataTable2 record all data from DataTable1 again.

How can I do a select command, that do this difference and record those datas in a third DataTable ?

Comment: You can't perform extensive queries on `DataTable`s with code. You can't, for example, simply write `SELECT * FROM TABLE;`. You can, however, use LINQ to write pseudo-queries.

Comment: So, how can I do a LINQ that compare 2 DataTable ?

Comment: This one can help you. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164144/c-how-to-compare-two-datatables-a-b-how-to-show-rows-which-are-in-b-but-not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will consider that there are two columns to identify the tables`(col1,col2)`

```
var rowsOnlyInDt1 = dt1.AsEnumerable().Where(r => !dt2.AsEnumerable()
                    .Any(r2 => r["col1"].Trim().ToLower() == r2["col1"].Trim().ToLower() && r["col2"].Trim().ToLower() == r2["col2"].Trim().ToLower()));

DataTable result = rowsOnlyInDt1.CopyToDataTable();//The third table
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
table1.Merge(table2); 
DataTable changesTable = table1.GetChanges();
```

Comment: The third DataTable, returns Null with GetChanges method.

Comment: No, I think changesTable will be populate with all the records Table1 have after merging.

Comment: Duplicates will be discarded, and only the differences between `table1` and `table2` will be populated into the `changesTable`.

Comment: @JamesJohnson I have tested it, but its populating `changesTable` with all the records from Table1. I think linq is the only solution to solve this problem.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. If anything, it should populate the changesTable with the records from table2.

Comment: Better you try this code: `DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            dt1.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            dt1.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));

            dt1.Rows.Add(1, "James");
            dt1.Rows.Add(2, "Thom");

            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
            dt2.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            dt2.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));

            dt2.Rows.Add(1, "James");
            dt2.Rows.Add(3, "Chris");
            dt1.Merge(dt2);
            DataTable dt3 = dt1.GetChanges();`

Comment: I think its happening because I am populating `DataTables` mannually. I need to call the AcceptChanges `dt1.AcceptChanges();` before merging.

Answer (score 0):

Using only SQL you can use `UNION` to easily find differences, there is an excellent article on the subject here: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2004/11/10/2737.aspx

The query will return an empty row set when the tables match, otherwise the differing rows are returned.