# Subtract two DataTables that have the same schema, e.g Minus SQL query

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I have two DataTables that have both the same schema (same columns names and types) .I want to get the rows that appear in the first and not in the second one.
Could anyone help me in this? Thanks.

Comment: You could use Linq's Except. You would probably have to provide your own EqualityComparer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7560742/difference-between-2-datatable

Comment: @WilliamXifaras the answer in the question you refer to is not working: it returns the rows that are in both DataTables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thankfully, MS has created [extension methods for `DataTable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.aspx) that let you use `Linq` methods (like [`Except`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx)) to query data rows, and written a [class that implements `IEqualityComparer<DataRow>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcomparer.aspx) that compares `DataRow` instances by their column values:

```
var rows = dt1.AsEnumerable()
              .Except(dt2.AsEnumerable(),DataRowComparer.Default);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write something like this:

```
var onlyIn1 = dataTable1.Where( row1 => !dataTable2.Rows.Any( row2 => row1["CustomerKey"] == row2["CustomerKey"]) ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
var onlyIn1 = db.Table1.Except(db.Table2).ToList();
```

I never test this, but it should work like T-SQL's `EXCEPT`

Comment: bluff and bla bla bla... Please be serious in your answers !