# Compare two DataTables for differences in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C#, how to compare two datatables A + B, how to show rows which are in B but not in A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164144/c-how-to-compare-two-datatables-a-b-how-to-show-rows-which-are-in-b-but-not)

I need to compare two datatables in c# to find the differences. The two datatables have the same schema. What is the best way to do it? Can it be done using linq queries? If yes, How?

Comment: if you're talkiong about sql server, and have the appropriate version of visual studio - just use the data base project availibale there

Comment: `DataTable`s or database tables?

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164144/c-how-to-compare-two-datatables-a-b-how-to-show-rows-which-are-in-b-but-not

Comment: I am referring to the DataTable in c#.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use LINQ to join the two `DataTable` objects, matching every column.  Then take the `IQueryable` and find all the rows in the first two `DataTable` objects which are not in the `IQueryable`.

**Example**:

```
private void SampleSolution(DataTable dt1, DataTable dt2)
{
    //If you have primary keys:
    var results = from table1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
                    join table2 in dt2.AsEnumerable() on table1.Field<int>("id") equals table2.Field<int>("id")
                    where table1.Field<int>("ColumnA") != table2.Field<int>("ColumnA") || table1.Field<int>("ColumnB") != table2.Field<int>("ColumnB") || table1.Field<String>("ColumnC") != table2.Field<String>("ColumnC")
                    select table1;
    //This will give you the rows in dt1 which do not match the rows in dt2.  You will need to expand the where clause to include all your columns.


    //If you do not have primarry keys then you will need to match up each column and then find the missing.
    var matched = from table1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
                    join table2 in dt2.AsEnumerable() on table1.Field<int>("ColumnA") equals table2.Field<int>("ColumnA")
                    where table1.Field<int>("ColumnB") == table2.Field<int>("ColumnB") || table1.Field<string>("ColumnC") == table2.Field<string>("ColumnC") || table1.Field<object>("ColumnD") == table2.Field<object>("ColumnD")
                    select table1;
    var missing = from table1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
                    where !matched.Contains(table1)
                    select table1;
    //This should give you the rows which do not have a match.  You will need to expand the where clause to include all your columns.
}
```

The code above should work, though I did not test it.

You could also check out [LINQ query on a DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855/linq-query-on-a-datatable) which has some useful information on using LINQ with DataTables.
I also find the [LINQ samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b) to be helpful when writting LINQ.

Comment: Yes it will be great if you can provide me an example as I am quite new to linq and c#

Comment: There you go.  Let me know if you have any problems.  Since setup would take a while I did not test them, but they should work.

Comment: thanks a ton, this looks exactly what I was looking for. Let me give it a try :)