# Comparing two datatables through Linq

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

Hi I'm trying to compare two `datatable` through Linq. But I get this exception:

> Specific cast is invalid

Please help me as I am new to Linq. This is the code I'm using:

```
var matched1 = from table1 in dtAvailableStores.AsEnumerable()
               join table2 in dtControlStores.AsEnumerable() 
               on table1.Field<int>("STORE_NBR") 
               equals table2.Field<int>("STORE_NBR")
               select table1;
```

Here `STORE_NBR` is a string value.

Answer (score 3):

You can have a fairly good idea with this piece of code:

```
var qry1 = datatable1.AsEnumerable().Select(a => new { MobileNo = a["ID"].ToString() });
var qry2 = datatable2.AsEnumerable().Select(b => new { MobileNo = b["ID"].ToString() });

var exceptAB = qry1.Except(qry2);

DataTable dtMisMatch = (from a in datatable1.AsEnumerable() join ab in exceptAB on a["ID"].ToString() equals ab.MobileNo select a).CopyToDataTable();
```

References:

1. [Compare two datatable using LINQ Query](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/344792/Compare-two-datatable-using-LINQ-Query)
2. [Compare two DataTables for differences in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984453/compare-two-datatables-for-differences-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

This would happen if that field isn't actually an `int`.