# Compare Two Linq Queries

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql, except

I have the following two queries that take information from the same table
I need to compare the two tables and find all the information that's value is different. Is there any way to do this without having to make a loop?

```
Dim housepress = (From press In db.PressInfo
                          Where press.PressName = pressname And press.CustomerID = "House"
                          Select press).ToList()

        Dim curpress = (From press In db.PressInfo
                        Where press.PressName = pressname And press.CustomerID = Customername
                        Select press)
```

I tried using `curpress.Except` but I get an error that "Local sequence cannot be used in Linq to SQL

Comment: check this for comparision http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984453/compare-two-datatables-for-differences-in-c

Comment: Why is the ToList there?

Comment: @Abdul thank you, I didn't see this question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two Lists for differences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/675699/compare-two-lists-for-differences)